# How to play media files with Ubuntu when booted from an USB pen drive?

Tags: boot, live-usb, media

I created a bootable pen drive from Ubuntu. When I boot my computer from it I can't open any of my media files such as music & videos. Please tell me how to open these files.

Comment: Which files? How do they not open?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the necessary media plugins.

You need an internet connection to achieve this.

To install the media plugins open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

Now you should be able to open and play most of the common media files.

In case you run into problems - make sure that all repositories are enabled :

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
```

Note :

These operations have to be performed every time after you booted again  from the USB drive when you did not create the Ubuntu installation media with a persistent storage functionality.

Comment: I think there is no need to add repos. They should be there already.

Comment: @Pilot6 : Thank you for your contribution ! You are right ... it should not be necessary, but for whatever reason sometimes you cannot install something without doing it. Nevertheless I changed the answer a little bit to make it more clear. Thanks again ! :)